# Gatling test returns 504 when making POST call for multipart/form-data

Tags: scala, performance, rest, https, gatling

Below is one of many attempted code to see if it works.

When I POST to another endpoint in same url, enpoint that accepts like a JSON body or a GET, it returns 200. But when I make a call to this point it always takes along time then returns a 504.

I've tried hitting the same point with ARC and the owner of the point showed me his result from Postman to tell me it's fine. The file I'm uploading is small in size as well.

This is from my latest attempts but I've tried many variation with RawFileBodyParts as well.

```
 .exec(
    http("POST multipart/form-data ")
       .post("https://url.to/the/api")
       .basicAuth("user", "password")
       .header("Content-Type","multipart/form-data")
       .bodyPart(RawFileBodyPart("file", "minuet2.pdf")
           .fileName("minuet2.pdf")
           .transferEncoding("binary")).asMultipartForm
```

Comment: Is it possible that there is a firewall preventing you from accessing that URL?

Comment: I have other api points, these accepts xml, but for those they are returning 200 so I would not think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue known and fixed: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3565
Will be shipped in next release.